# Jest, Babel and Storybook, export vs module.exports

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I am using Jest to test my services and Storybook and Babel to develop my React components.

I have a service which my component needs to use. I currently export with `module.exports = someFunction;` and it passes my Jest unit tests, but storybook tells me `Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'` in the browser console.

If I change the service to `export default someFunction`, the component works but the Jest unit test fails with `SyntaxError: Unexpected token export`.

*What do I do to make both work?*

Notes:

- I don't care whether I consistently export with `module.exports` or `export`. I have no real preference at this time.
- I'm prepared to use a different unit-testing library, but I wasn't happy with Ava last time, and I don't remember having any luck with unit testing software and babel.
- Last time I was using Babel I didn't have a problem with `module.exports`. Would a downgrade help? If so, what would I downgrade to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding a file called `babel.config.js` with the contents:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/env']
};
```

If anyone has a better answer or believes they can educate me in the numerous areas I'm sure I'm shortcoming, they are welcome to do so.